# Error when select max value of the code-igniter model

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

My `codeigniter` model contents `mysql` select_max query. I want to select my `pro_id` column max value.
When used following code it's work

```
$maxid = $this->db->query('SELECT MAX(prop_id) AS `maxid` FROM `tble_proposal`')->row()->maxid;
echo $maxid;
```

But if i used `select_max` function, i cant get the max value as number. what is the missing here?

```
$this->db->select_max('prop_id');      
$maxid = $this->db->get('tble_proposal');       
echo $maxid;
```

**error says**: 
`Object of class CI_DB_mysql_result could not be converted to string`

Comment: as ur error its a object ... change echo with print_r($maxid); then see which value is in object u need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to echo object from your query .that's your  are getting this error

You need to fetch data from your query . Use `->row()` to fetch it

```
$maxid = $this->db->get('tble_proposal');   
$max=$maxid->row();    
echo $max->maxid;
```

Read https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html

Comment: perfect & accept the answer with small modification `echo $max->maxid;` should be `echo $max->prop_id;`

Comment: Why you create alias in your query as `MAX(prop_id) AS maxid` so it is `maxid`

Answer (score 2):

```
$maxid = $this->db->query('SELECT MAX(prop_id) AS `maxid` FROM `tble_proposal`')->row()->maxid;
echo $maxid;
```

this works because u get `row` and `rowobject`.

try with

```
echo $maxid[0]->maxid;
```

or

```
echo $maxid->maxid;
```

or

`print_r($maxid)` and see what it return